# Getting error when using learningratescheduler with keras and SGD optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, keras, deep-learning

I want to decrease the learning rate in each epoch. I am using Keras. I got this error when I run my code.

```
{Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-2983b4be581f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Gehan Mohamed/cnn_learningratescheduler.py', wdir='C:/Users/Gehan Mohamed')

  File "C:\Users\Gehan Mohamed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 96, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<keras.callbacks.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler object at 0x000001E7C7B8E780>) with an unsupported type (<class 'keras.callbacks.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler'>) to a Tensor.
Attempt to convert a value (<keras.callbacks.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler object at 0x000001E7C7B8E780>) with an unsupported type (<class 'keras.callbacks.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler'>) to a Tensor}.
```

How can I solve this error?

```
def step_decay(epochs):
    if epochs <50:
        lrate=0.1
        return lrate
    if epochs >50:
        lrate=0.01
        return lrate            
            
lrate = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
sgd = SGD(lr=lrate, decay=0, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
callbacks_list = [lrate,callback]
filesPath=getFilesPathWithoutSeizure(i, indexPat)
history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75), 
                                validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, start=75),
                                steps_per_epoch=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*25))), 
                                validation_steps=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*75))),
                                verbose=2,
                                epochs=300, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Comment: When you get errors in your code please post the full error traceback that you get. Edit your original post with it, rather than posting it as a comment as comments have very little formatting making it hard to read

Answer (score 3):

In this part of the code:

```
lrate = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
sgd = SGD(lr=lrate, decay=0, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
```

You are setting the learning rate of `SGD` as the callback, that is incorrect, you should set an initial learning rate to SGD:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=0, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
```

And pass the callback list to `model.fit`, maybe it's an artifact of a previous variable that you also called `lrate`.

Comment: I want to decrease the learning rate in each epoch.How can i do that by using SGD optimizer?? , I can't set an initial learning rate to SGD as the learning would be update in each epoch

Comment: @gigi No, that thinking is incorrect, you set an initial learning rate and the LearningRateScheduler callback will set the learning rate across epochs.

Comment: it doesn't work.Learning rate doesn't updated in each epoch. i set the initial learning rate=0.1 in SGD  `sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=0, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)`

Comment: @gigi How exactly are you checking that it does not work? I use that callback regularly and I know it works fine.

Comment: only initial learning rate used it doesn't update the learning rate across each epoch .

Comment: @gigi That doesn't answer my question, your decay function only reduces the learning rate after 50 epochs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as shown below to reduce learning rate by a custom value after each epoch

```
def scheduler(epoch, lr):
  if epoch < 1:
    return lr
  else:
    return lr * tf.math.exp(-0.1)
```

Above is the function that reduces the learning rate, now this function should be called after each epoch. Below is the initialization of the function using LearningRateScheduler( you can check the documentation on tensorflow website for more details on this)

```
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)
```

Now, let us call this from the fit method.

```
history = model.fit(trainGen, validation_data=valGen, validation_steps=val_split//batch_size, epochs=200, steps_per_epoch= train_split//batch_size, callbacks=[callback])
```

As you see above you just have to configure the initialed scheduler in the fit method and run it. You will notice after each epoch the learning rate keeps decreasing as per what you have set in the scheduler function.